# R Shiny, no stack trace and unused argument

Tags: r, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have the following code which should aggregate over a column chosen by user input and plot the result in a bar graph using ggplot

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
options(shiny.port = 8000)

churn = read.csv('churn.csv')
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectInput(
        inputId = 'column',
        label = 'choose column',
        choices = c(names(churn)[2:5],names(churn)[7:18],names(churn)[21]),
        
    ),
    
    plotOutput('bar')
)
server <- function(input,ouput){
    result <- reactive({
        churn %>% group_by(input$column) %>% summarize(counts = n())
    })

    output$bar <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(result(),aes_string(x=input$column,y="counts",fill = input$column))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Instead the app immediately crashes with the following error:

```
Warning: Error in server: unused argument (output = list(<environment>, function (x) 
x))
  [No stack trace available]
Error in server(...) : 
  unused argument (output = list(<environment>, function (x) 
x))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in your `server <- function(input,ouput){` line: `ouput` should be `output`.

Comment: I am embarrassed.